# Seo Friendly Filter URLs

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, htaccess, seo

Is it possible to create more SEO friendly filter URLS?

Instead of:

```
https://example.com/product-category/rings/?filter_material=gold
```

Then:

```
https://example.com/product-category/rings/rings-in-gold/
```

?

Comment: Yes, but it's probably easier to use [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)..

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing @SallyCJ. So you would basically make a redirection for the above two urls? And Google / Search engines would accept that? It's not too ideal, as the URL would still remain the same, even when shared, but it's at least better. I also thought about making some kind of subcategory, but not sure how that would work out.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible.

#### Option 1: Programmatically using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)

1. Add the rewrite rule:

   ```php
   /* The rule matches:
    * example.com/product-category/rings/rings-in-gold/
    * example.com/product-category/rings/rings-in-gold/page/<number>/
    */
   add_action( 'init', function () {
       add_rewrite_rule(
           '^product-category/rings/rings-in-gold(?:/page/(\d+)|)/?$',
           // $matches[1] is the (\d+) (page number) from the above Regex, if any.
           'index.php?product_cat=rings&filter_material=gold&paged=$matches[1]',
           'top'
       );
   } );
   ```

   For other categories, just copy the above `add_rewrite_rule()` and replace the text "rings", "rings-in-gold" and "gold".
2. Register the custom query var `filter_material`:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'query_vars', function ( $vars ) {
       $vars[] = 'filter_material';
       return $vars;
   } );
   ```

   You can use another name for the query var, but make sure the name does not already exist.
3. Flush/regenerate the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings page.

And then in your theme/template, you can get the "material" filter value like so:

```php
$material = get_query_var( 'filter_material' );
```

#### Option 2: Use the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

*I'm not the author of the plugin and I have no affiliation with him or the plugin, but it's an awesome plugin with a user-friendly UI for creating redirections, both standard ones (where the URL in the browser's address bar changes) and pass-through which works like the `add_rewrite_rule()`, i.e. no URL change.*

The plugin also comes with cool features such as tracking, so if you like that and don't want to mess with coding, then you can check [here](https://redirection.me/support/) how to use the plugin. But here's an example based on the `add_rewrite_rule()` example above:

1. [Create a new redirection](https://redirection.me/support/create-redirects/).
2. Apply these settings: (*click the cog icon* to see the "When matched" option)

   ```
   Source URL: /product-category/rings/rings-in-gold(?:/page/(\d+)|)/?$
   Regex: Yes (check the box)
   When matched: Pass-through
   Target URL: /product-category/rings/?filter_material=gold&paged=$2
   ```

   Once again, for other categories, just replace the relevant text.

With this plugin, you don't need to register the custom query var (see step #2 in Option 1 above) and simply use `$_GET['filter_material']` in your theme/template:

```php
// Simplified example in PHP 7 syntax.
$material = $_GET['filter_material'] ?? '';
```

**Note: Before you try the second option, make sure to edit your file and remove the code taken from Option 1 and visit the permalink settings page. Alternatively, use another category (e.g. `earrings`) when testing the second option. This is so that you know both options actually work. :)**