# How to do SEO friendly filters urls?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, htaccess, seo

I have a WordPress website. It uses Woocommerce. All products are loaded and attributes are created.

When the user opens the catalog page and selects the filter values, there are problems with the URL.

For example, a user opens a catalog page, selects a product `category=rings`, sets the filter `Stones=brilliant`

The link looks like this:

```
http://example.com/shop/rings/?filter_stones=brilliant&query_type_stones=or
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
http://example.com/shop/rings/rings-with-brilliant
```

I need the page to have the content of the page of the first link, but the URL of the second.

I found an answer here: [Seo Friendly Filter URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/358425/seo-friendly-filter-urls/358484#358484?newreg=dd9b70bdb01148b6b8511114cdc38c6d)

But I don’t understand how to use it. In which file should I paste the code from this answer?
Or maybe you can tell me other solutions?

Comment: Whilst [the question you link to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/358425/seo-friendly-filter-urls/358484#358484?newreg=dd9b70bdb01148b6b8511114cdc38c6d) may not be as well written as yours, it would seem to be _identical_. Any further answers should be directed to that earlier question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seo Friendly Filter URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/358425/seo-friendly-filter-urls)

Comment: Yes, they are almost the same. But the answer suggested to the attached question does not work in my case. Of course I didn't use it literally, but for some reason it doesn't help: the get request does not disappear from the links